# Infix to PostFix calculator in C - Segmentation fault when assigning the value of the int to char[] with cast

Tags: c, stack, calculator, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm trying to build a calculator that gets an InFix expression, coverts it into a PostFix expression, and then returns/prints the result.
I**'m currently at the conversion stage.**
I'm getting a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) on this line:                    PostFix[postIndex] = (char) a;

Why am I getting this error?

Your help would be appreciated.
thanks,

```
int Calc (char _infix[])
{
    char PostFix[10];
    Stack* myStack;
    int a;
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t postIndex = 0;
    myStack = StackCreate(5,10);
    if (myStack == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while (_infix[index] != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(_infix[index]))
        {
            PostFix[postIndex] = _infix[index];
            ++index;
            ++postIndex;
            continue;
        }
        if (_infix[index] == '+' || _infix[index] == '-' || _infix[index] == '*' || _infix[index] == '/')
        {
            switch (_infix[index])
            {
                case '+': 
                case '-':
                StackTop(myStack , &a);
                while ((char) a != '(' && ! StackIsEmpty(myStack))
                {
                    PostFix[postIndex] = (char) a;
                    ++postIndex;
                    StackPop(myStack , &a);
                    StackTop(myStack , &a);
                    break;
                }
                StackPush(myStack, _infix[index]);
                break;

                case '*': 
                case '/':
                StackTop(myStack ,  &a);
                while (((char) a != '(' || (char) a != '-' || (char) a != '+') && ! StackIsEmpty(myStack))
                {
                    PostFix[postIndex] = (char) a;
                    ++postIndex;
                    StackPop(myStack , &a);
                    StackTop(myStack , &a);
                    continue;
                }
                StackPush(myStack , a);
                break;

            }
            continue; 
        }
        if (_infix[index] == '(')
        {
            StackPush(myStack, _infix[index]);
            ++index;
            ++postIndex;
            continue;
        }
        if (_infix[index] == ')')
        {
            StackTop(myStack , &a);
            while (StackIsEmpty(myStack) == false && (char) a != '(')
            {
                PostFix[postIndex] = (char) a;
                ++postIndex;
                StackPop(myStack , &a);
                StackTop(myStack , &a);
                continue;
            }  
            ++index;
            continue;
        }
    }
    while(StackIsEmpty == false)
    {
        StackPop(myStack ,  &a);
        PostFix[postIndex] = (char) a;

    }
    printf("Your new string is: %s\n", PostFix);
}
return true;
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that `postIndex` is out of range.

Comment: I'd also be worried about `PostFix` not being null-terminated.

Comment: In case you are one of the unlucky ones that doesn't have psychic powers you could always use a debugger and/or debug print statements to try and debug the code for yourself.

Comment: You should split this monster function into several ones. Then you will get rid of the `continue` spaghetti programming too.

Comment: @silkyit What is the input infix expression? If it starts with a digit, which sounds likely, then `postIndex` won't be 0 at the line you mentioned since the number will have been stored. 10 characters (minus termination!) for a general infix expression is rather small, too.

Comment: @unwind the input is a string. I forgot the increase the index on every iteration and that's what caused the segmentation fault.